# Regular expression to extract argument in a LaTeX command

Tags: regex, latex

I have a large LaTeX document where I have defined a macro like this:

```
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left|#1\right|}
```

I want to get rid of it by replacing in all the document `\abs{...}` by `\left|...\right|`, so I am thinking in a regular expression. I am familiar with their basics but I do not know how to find the bracket that closes the expression, given that the following situations are possible:

1. `\abs{(2+x)^3}`
2. `\abs{\frac{2}{3}}`
3. `\abs{\frac{2}{\sin(2\abs{x})}}`

What I have been able to do for the moment is `\\abs\{([^\}]*)\}` and then replace as `\left\1\right|`but it is only able to deal with the pieces of code of the first kind only.

By the way, I am using the TeXstudio regular expression engine.

Comment: You may find help over at [tex.stackexchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks @Celeo, but since this is a question more related with regular expressions than with LaTeX I think it fits better here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I did a little more of research and I managed to solve it. According to [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19863847/3802009) in a similar question, it suffices to use recursive regular expressions and a text editor that supports them, for example Sublime Text 2 (I could not do it with TeXstudio). This does the trick:

Find: `\\abs\{(([^\{\}]|(?R))*)\}`

Replace: `\\left|\1\\right|`

EDIT 1: Actually this solves only the two first cases, but fails with the third, so any idea on how to improve the regular expression would be appreciated.

EDIT 2: See comment from @CasimiretHippolyte for full answer using `\\abs\{((?>[^{}]+|\{(?1)\})*)\}`

Comment: Good research effort. You can try it without escaping the curly brackets. Or better, if supported: `\\abs{((?>[^{}]+|{(?1)})*)}`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Humm that one does not seem to be supported. Actually, I have edited the answer since the solution for the third case is still open.

Comment: It seems that you must to escape curly brackets that are out of a character class in sublimetext2, so: `\\abs\{((?>[^{}]+|\{(?1)\})*)\}` *(the `(?1)` repeats the subpattern in the capture group 1, `(?R)` repeats the whole pattern)*

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Great! That works like a charm! Would you mind turning your comment as an answer so I can accept it?